# I get Error 404.0 - Not Found when browsing to the localhost IdentityServer3 discovery endpoint

Tags: c#, owin, identityserver3

I've been trying to set up an IdentityServer as per IdentityServer3, using VS 2019 pro, with all updates and targetFramework="4.6.1", but when trying to do so e.g. https://localhost:44324/.well-known/openid-configuration. I get an HTTP 404.0 Resource not found or moved error.

The code is as per the code on GitHub, except that VS forced me to put the .cs files into the 'App_Code' folder.
The certificate is correctly in the Bin/Config folder and the Startup.cs  looks in that same directory for it. 
Startup.cs is in the root of the project.
SSL is also enabled and the SSL url is https://localhost:44324/
and it is set in the property pages as the start URL as specified in the help file.
I also created the project on the 'older' 4.5 C# web empty template.
I used Nuget to download the packages.
Project structure as per image.

I've tried breakpointing the Configuration in the Startup class, but the breakpoint does not get hit.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
        });
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"bin\Config\idsrv3test.pfx"), "idsrv3test");
    }
}
```

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by not starting with an empty ASP.Net Web Site, (from the Previous Versions installed types), but by Selecting Web -> ASP.Net Web applications and then selecting the MVC template and then creating the classes as per the Setup documentation.